# How to determine if a field is NULL or NOT NULL in mysql workbench gui?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there any gui functionality within mysql workbench where you can view whether a field is set to NULL or NOT NULL?

For example this:

```
CREATE TABLE Peoples (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR (200) NULL,
last_name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Is displayed as

```
Table Peoples
=============
id, first_name, last_name
-------------
id               int(11) PK
first_name       varchar(200)
last_name        varchar(100)
```

In the Object Information tab.  The object information tab does not specify that the first_name is NULL and the last name is NOT NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under "Data Modelling" use "Create EER Model From Existing Database" or open up an existing model of the desired database if you have one. Then select the desired table and the bottom window will show the table's properties. The "Columns" tab will show what columns are NULL by default.

Comment: Where's "Data Modelling"?  Is it a tab? Is it on the menu?

Comment: In the version I'm using (5.2 CE), it's in the middle of the home screen; [link](http://docs.huihoo.com/mysql/refman-5.5-en/wb-intro.html#wb-home)

Answer (score 15):

It seems unfortunate that one would need to create an entire EER model just to see if a column is nullable.. another workaround i found is to right-click on the table and choose 'Alter Table' and the editor that comes up shows the NN column, checked or not (version 5.2.47).

Comment: this is useful, better than creating the entire Model.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the table and select "Table inspector". This will open up the table info. Then select the "Columns" tab. You can then see which fields are nullable or not